# Rails define custom json structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm attempting to structure a json response to mimic an existing structure we have elsewhere in our application (using jbuilder templates). In this specific use case, we are unable to use the jbuilder template because we are preparing the json data for a live update job being fired from a model method, not responding to a server call in the controller.

Desired structure:

```
{"notes": {
  "1": {
    "id": "1", 
    "name": "Jane", 
    ... 
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Joe", 
    ... 
  }
 }
}
```

Jbuilder Template (for reference):

```
json.notes do
  for note in notes 
    json.set! note.id.to_s do
      json.id note.id.to_s
      json.name note.name
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried defining a to_builder method in the model class (below), per the jbuilder docs, and active model serializers but can't seem to get the hashes nested under the id attribute. Any direction would be appreciated!

to_builder method

```
def to_builder
  Jbuilder.new do |note|
    note.set! self.id do
      note.(self, :id, :name, ...)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just plain Ruby?

```
notes.each_with_object({"notes": {}}) do |note, hash|
  hash["notes"][note.id.to_s] = note.as_json
end
```

Or AMS:

```
adapter = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter
notes.each_with_object({"notes": {}}) do |note, hash|
  hash["notes"][note.id.to_s] = adapter.create(NoteSerializer.new(note))
end
```

Comment: Admittedly I never was a JBuilder fan (DHH is probally the only JBuilder fan and thats just because he built it). Have this weird awkward (and sloooow)  templating DSL to build hashes and arrays is just so backwards. At least AMS has OOP working for it.

Comment: oh yes, slow it is. Burns bright in every profiler report I've ran :)

Comment: Would love to stick with plain ruby - this looks promising, thank you. Did you mean `notes.each_with_object` instead of `users.each_with_object` above?

Comment: I keep getting `undefined method id' for {:notes=>{}}:Hash` am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry my bad should be `notes` instead of `users` and the arguments where switched. I can never seem to remember the arguments order for `each_with_object`.